# How can I validate number in wicket 1.5.3?

Tags: validation, wicket

Ive heard, about NumberTextField, and a parametrized Textfield. But Im looking for something that validate if there is a number on the textbox, and instead of throw an exception it should show error on feedback panel. What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you parameterize your textfield with `TextField<Integer>`, you will get a feedbackmessage that the input is not valid for type Integer. You should also parameterize the model object with integer. thats it, thats all you need to do. you do not need any custom validation.
you can also use some standard number validators like `RangeValidator<Integer>` if you need some extended validation.

Comment: In case you wonder where the exact error message of the validator for the parameterized textfield comes from: have a look a the Application.properties file of Wicket.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own Validator to the TextField. That Validator should check if the input value is a number. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/create-custom-validator-in-wicket/) you can find an example about how to implement your own validator.

Comment: not sure this works. input is first converted, than validated. And convertion will most likely fail for any non number input i 'm afraid

Comment: As far as I understood the problem he wants to have a TextField and wants to check if input is number or not. If no number, an error should be shown as a feedback message. I think, a validator would work well for this kind of problem.

Comment: with a textField yes, with a NumberTextField no ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can implement a IsNumberValidator or something, but on these kind of situations I'd rather validate on client-side with javascript, makes more sense. ([Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) is a nice JQuery plugin that is easy to use). You can then have an extra validation on server side in case the bad user does something naughty, so your application don't get messed up because of the bad input.